# (Kotlin) How can i execute lambda () -> Unit like function parameter through reflection

Tags: kotlin, lambda, reflection

i have code

```
object Boo {
    val lambda: () -> Unit = { print("lambda") }
    operator fun invoke(init: Foo.() -> Unit){
    }
}
```

And I don't understand how can i execute **init** in reflection.

For example, I can execute **lambda** class member like this

```
    ((this.javaClass.kotlin
.declaredMemberProperties as List<*>)[0] asKProperty1<Boo,*>).invoke(this) //works
```

so **init** i get like parameter **invoke** function only

```
    val kparameter: KParameter = this.javaClass.kotlin.functions
.first { it.name == "invoke" }.parameters[0]
```

but i can't do anything with it!

**Can anyone help me with this question?**

Comment: It's just a parameter of a function. You can't invoke it without having a value to invoke. Imagine the function has an Int parameter. How do you inspect what value the Int is? It doesn't have a value until something calls the function.

Comment: hm, ok. But lambda it's not just a parameter. It is an Object. And when we have created instance of Boo, invoke was executed automatically, and so we can get this instance, is not it?

Comment: It is just a parameter. The object is what a caller would pass to the function. I don’t know what you’re talking about when you say this invoke function was executed automatically.